# nginx reverse proxy with part of url as dynamic

Tags: docker, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

i have a django app and nginx as services on docker-compose. Am using nginx as a reverse proxy.

here is the docker compose file

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  # nginx reverse proxy
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.17.10
    container_name: nginx   
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - app
  app:
    image: django-app-image
    conatinter_name: app
    expose
      - 8001
    restart: on-failure
```

here is the nginx configuration

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 1;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    # sendfile on;

    upstream django-app {
        server app:8001;
    }
    server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        location /vocal-bm{
            client_max_body_size 0;
            proxy_pass         http://django-app/vocal-bm;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
}
```

**This is what i want to achieve:**

I should visit `http://localhost/vocal-bm/<some-variable>`

and the route served should be `http://django-app/vocal-bm/<some-variable>`

The above configuration just routes to `http://django-app`

How do I get it to work i.e route to `http://django-app/vocal-bm/<some-variable>`

**What I have tried**
adding a trailing slash on the proxy_pass `proxy_pass http://django-app/vocal-bm/;`
but a get `http://django-app/vocal-bm//<some-variable>` with the double slash before the dynamic variable.

I have also tried the rewrite but it gives `http://django-app` also